# How to get a version string from a website and compare it?

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script for updating a program but I only want to download it if the version number is greater on http://come-join.us/update/test.txt than it is in the Test.txt file.

How do I compare those strings?

```
$FileName = "$PSScriptRoot\SysinternalsSuite.zip"

Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Test.txt

(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.dropbox.com/s/12uecxcxq2rt0s4/um.zip?dl=1',"$FileName ");
(new-object -com shell.application).namespace("$PSScriptRoot").CopyHere((new-object -com shell.application).namespace("$FileName").Items(),16)
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
  Remove-Item $FileName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the `[version]` type accelerator to make the comparison. For example:

```
$LocalVersion = [version](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\test.txt)
$RemoteVersion = [version](Invoke-RestMethod http://come-join.us/update/test.txt)

If ($LocalVersion -lt $RemoteVersion) {
    $true
}
```

The Version accelerator converts the version string in to a System.Version .NET class object:

```
~\Documents> $RemoteVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      1      -1
```

With which you can then do comparisons using all the standard comparison operators.